# Splitting an SQL Table into Sub-Tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a massive table of data that needs to be aggregated in some way. The data is far too large for this to be done in one-hit, so I first split the table into N sub-tables and perform the aggregations on the separate chunks. The code that does the splitting (in the case below splitting into 3 separate sub-tables), is

```
SELECT [EpiSer], 
       [SINum], 
       [VolNum], 
       [CTPQty], 
       [VolAmt], 
       [CTPActivityGroupCode],  
       NTILE(3) OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS TilingIdx 
INTO [_Stage2] 
FROM [_Stage1];
GO
```

To create the second of the sub-tables I use

```
SELECT [EpiSer], 
       [SINum], 
       [VolNum], 
       [CTPQty], 
       [VolAmt], 
       [CTPActivityGroupCode] 
INTO [_Stage2_Part2] 
FROM [_Stage2] 
WHERE [TilingIdx] = 2; -- This number is changed for each split 1, 2 and 3
GO
```

The problem is that the aggregation query I use on each of the generated sub-tables groups on `[EpiSer]` (of which there are duplicates). So splitting this way, could split record with the same `[EpiSer]` into different sub-tables, so when I perform my aggregation, we are missing some records. For reference the aggregation query [for sub-table 2] is

```
SELECT [s1].[EpiSer] as ActivityRecordID, 
       [s1].[CTPActivityGroupCode] as ActCstID, 
       [t].[ResCstID], 
       [s1].[VolAmt], 
       [s1].[CTPQty] AS ActCnt, 
       SUM([s1].[VolAmt] * [t].[OCostUnit]) AS TotOCst, 
       SUM([s1].[VolAmt] * [t].[FCostUnit]) AS TotFCst 
INTO [_Agg2] 
FROM [_Stage2_Part2] AS s1 
    INNER JOIN 
        [DriversCtp] AS t ON [s1].[VolNum] = [t].[VolNum] 
GROUP BY [s1].[EpiSer], 
         [s1].[CTPActivityGroupCode], 
         [t].[ResCstID], 
         [s1].[VolAmt], 
         [s1].[CTPQty];
GO
```

So, my question is, how can I split the original table into N sub-tables, but ensure that records with the same `[EpiSer]` are kept in the same sub-tables?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes, redoing the work of the query optimizer is hard. Are you sure the original query can't be optimized any further other than by physically splitting the data yourself? I have run queries over tables with 8 billion rows, and while this certainly takes a while (seeing as how all data needs to be read and all) they're not "far too large to be done in one hit". Are you running into memory limits? Temp table overflows?

Comment: Yes, it is many-to-many inner join with aggregation. Splitting is my only option. After the splitting, I then combine the tables back into one big one. I am thinking that perhaps I just need to post process the final joined table and merge records with duplicate values for the columns that were grouped by in the aggregate query - I think this is what I will try now in fact. Thanks for your response.

Comment: "Splitting is my only option" . That the point you should reconsider... Working with huge table is not a problem when things are done the right way.

Comment: Maybe you should so try to rank your big table with a dense_rank() on EpiSer so that you could use ntile() on it. Not sure it helps, sure it will take a long long time...

Comment: Given that you're grouping on s1.VolAmt, you can bring that out of the sum (ie s1.VolAmt * SUM(t.FCostUnit) ). With that change you might be able to aggregate each of your tables separately and then join on the aggregated result.

Comment: you may go for Partitioning . and after this you need  pagination  of special type i.e.  same [EpiSer] are kept in same page ( or pageindex).Ntile will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this using another `UPDATE` after splitting the data in groups. As you are ordering by `ID`, we can find the minimum group for each `ID`:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [id] TINYINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
   ,[value] TINYINT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([value])
VALUES (1), (1), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (7), (7), (7), (7), (7), (7), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11);


SELECT *
      ,NTILE(3) OVER(ORDER BY Id)  AS [GroupID]
INTO #DataSource
FROM @DataSource;


SELECT *
      ,MIN([GroupID]) OVER(PARTITION BY [value])
FROM #DataSource

DROP TABLE #DataSource;
```

[image]

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT [id]
          ,MIN([GroupID]) OVER(PARTITION BY [value]) AS [GroupID]
    FROM #DataSource
)
UPDATE #DataSource
SET [GroupID] = B.[GroupID]
FROM #DataSource A
INNER JOIN DataSource B
    ON A.[id] = B.[id];
```

I am not sure how this is going to affect your performance, but cannot figure it how to `fix` the grouping inline.

---

Also, if you are using`SQL Server 2012+` you can check the [clustered column store indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-columnstore-index-transact-sql) - they can be used for [optimizing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-query-performance) aggregations across huge tables.